# How do I get the non-selected rownumbers?

Tags: r

I created a training and testing subset from my original data:

```
df <- data.frame(var = seq(1, 200, by = 2))
train.rows <- sample(1:100, 75, replace = FALSE)
df.train <- df[train.rows,]
df.test <- df[-train.rows,]
```

How can I see the numbers of the rows from the original dataframe (`df`) that I selected to be in `df.test`? (To see the ones that I selected to be in `df.train`, I would just check out `trains.rows`. But that is not possible for `-train.rows`)

Edit: the title is about the fact that I specify/select rows for a training set and now I just want to know the ones that I didn't select for the training set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can approach this :

1) Since this is one-column dataframe use `drop = FALSE`

```
df.train <- df[train.rows,, drop = FALSE]
df.test <- df[-train.rows,, drop = FALSE]
```

You can now see row numbers in `df.train` and `df.test` which can be extracted with `rownames(df.train)` and `rownames(df.test)`.

2) You can use `setdiff` to include the index of rows which is present in `df.test`.

```
setdiff(1:nrow(df), train.rows)
```